# When is the product of a matrix A, a diagonal matrix, and A transpose positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Suppose I have two matrices $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $D \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$, where $D$ is diagonal, and $m > n$. Is there a simple set of necessary and sufficient conditions for when the matrix $A^T D A$ is positive definite?

A few observations so far:

- A *necessary* condition is that $\text{rank}(A) = n$. If $\text{rank}(A) < n$, then $A$ has a nontrivial kernel, so there exists a non-zero vector $u \in \mathbb R^m$ such that $u^T A^T D A u = 0$.
- A *sufficient* condition (assuming $A$ has full rank) is that all of the diagonal entries of $D$ are positive.

One possibility I'm stuck on is Weyl's inequality. Notice that $A^T D A$ can be written as a linear combination of outer products of the columns $A_i$:
$$
A^T D A = \sum_{i=1}^n D_{ii} A_i A_i^T = \sum_{i: D_{ii} > 0} D_{ii} A_i A_i^T + \sum_{i : D_{ii} \le 0} D_{ii} A_i A_i^T
$$
Let $\lambda_1(M) \ge \lambda_2(M) \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_m(M)$ denote the eigenvalues of a matrix $M \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$. By Weyl's inequality, for any $i = 1, \dots, n$, we know
\begin{equation}
\lambda_i\left( \sum_{i: D_{ii} > 0} D_{ii} A_i A_i^T \right) + \lambda_m \left( \sum_{i : D_{ii} \le 0} D_{ii} A_i A_i^T \right) \le \lambda_i(A^T D A)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lambda_i \left( \sum_{i : D_{ii} \le 0} D_{ii} A_i A_i^T \right) + \lambda_m\left(  \sum_{i: D_{ii} > 0} D_{ii} A_i A_i^T  \right) \le \lambda_i(A^T D A)
\end{equation}
To establish a lower bound on the eigenvalues of $A^T D A$, we would need to choose $i = m$. But the smallest eigenvalue of each $D_{ii} A_i^T A_i$ for $D_{ii} > 0$ is zero, while the smallest eigenvalue of each $D_{ii} A_i^T A_i$ for $D_{ii} \le 0$ is non-positive. Thus it seems these inequalities are useless for establishing $A^T D A$ as positive definite.

Does anyone know of some stronger results?

Comment: Are you sure $m$ and $n$ aren't mixed up anywhere? If $m<n$, $A$ is $m\times n$ and $D$ is $n\times n$ then $DA$ isn't defined and $A$ can't have rank $n$.

Comment: $A^TDA$ is positive definite iff $A$ has full column rank and the diagonal of $D$ is positive. Just consider $x^T(A^TDA)x=(Ax)^TD(Ax)$.

Comment: @stewbasic, thanks for pointing that out. It should be $m > n$, and $D \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$. I've edited the question to make this fix.

Comment: @KDS I'm not sure what sort of condition is useful to you. The set $C=\{x\in\mathbb R^m\mid x^TDx>0\}$ can be described somewhat explicitly, and one equivalent condition is that $C\cup\{0\}$ contains the image of $A$.